# How to make <p> wrap around a word that is larger than the rest of the text

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my `<p>` text to wrap around a couple words I made very bold and large with a span tag. I'm linking a code pen.

HTML

```
<div class="infoContainer">                                     <!--BEGIN INFO SECTION-->
    <div class="bio">
        <h3>STORY OF THE BAND</h3>
        <p><span id="bioPop">Coldclock<br>Knockout</span> is a hard rock band hailing from Tampa Bay, Florida.
            The band formed in April of 2015 after a vocalist Robby Lynch and drummer Bryan Acton
            placed a Craigslist ad seeking a bassist.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS is in Codepen link because it wouldn't format properly.

[Here's a code pen link.](http://codepen.io/Ominix/pen/pgZBXE).

Comment: Try reading this article. [link] (http://techwelkin.com/wrap-text-around-a-div-element)

Comment: Thanks so much! I just floated the span. I wish I could give you a point for the help, man!

Answer (score 0):

Only add `float:left` in your #bioPop.

It should work!!